# Set nested resource controller model to child object of parent route model

Tags: ember.js

this may sound abit confusing but I'll try my best to explain it.

I have a `loans` route, and then I have a nested resource called product under it. One `loan` can have many products, and when you select to view one of the products I redirect to the `product` nested resource. The problem is that my application supports working with unsaved data. So initially when you create a new loan, you can add new products without saving the loan (my loan model has a hasMany property on product), but when I navigate to the product route, I need to access the loan model on my loans route, and get all the products the loan currently has, and then find one according to the id in the URL, but I'm facing the issue that when I get the loans controller its model is still null, I guess it's because the loans route is executed after the product route.

I'm taking the wrong approach or  is there a way to get access to the loans model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access the loans controller and its model from the child controller if you declare it as a dependency.

Just add `needs: 'loans'` (with your actual loans route name) inside your product controller and then you can access the loans controller like this: `this.get('controllers.loans')`.

You can read more here: http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/

#### Update to fully address original question

From within the ProductRoute you should be able to access a parent model by doing this.modelFor('loan'). Make sure you use the actual route name declared in the Router.map.

Comment: Yes, but I need to access it in my Product route, because there I get the route parameters, which is the product id, so I can set the model to the Product controller, or is there a way to access route parameters in the controller?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't fully understand your need for getting it from the Route. From within the ProductRoute you should be able to access a parent model by doing `this.modelFor('loan')`. You should use the actual route name you used in the Router.map. Let me know if this answers your question and I'll edit the answer above to make it more thorough.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I'll mark as answer, which I could give you more points, I had been stucked for a while, really appreciate it.